# Reflective evolutionary algorithm

Tags: popularity-contest

You have to write a program, implementing a function `digitsum(int i)`. The program has to modify its own code (for languages, where this is not possible with f.e. [reflection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_%28computer_programming%29), please be creative) to get itself to solve the goal.

You start with

```
function digitsum(int i){
    return i;
}
```

and implement an [evolutionary algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evolutionary_algorithm) that will modify the above function until it returns valid [digitsums](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digit_sum) on function call.

As this is a popularity contest, you have very much free hands, please be creative!

**Guidelines:**

- Start with the defined function (translated to your language of course).
- Print out at least the fittest function of each generation.
- Print out your working solution tested for 0 < i < 10000.
- Be creative!

**Do not:**

- Hint your program to the solution, please use your whole language options!
- Throw errors to the console.
- Use any external input. You can write and save to files created by your program. No internet.

The valid solution with the most upvotes wins!

Comment: Does `no libraries` allowed mean no libc?

Comment: i have removed the `no libraries` as it would be to complex imo, so the voters can decide if there are to many libraries used!

Comment: +1 Hard interesting question. Will need some hours to produce an answer. Unfortunately don't expect to get more than say 2 or 3 answers.

Comment: *wonders* What is the difference between this and a recursive function? I can't quite figure it out, as in I can't visualize the scenario **feels retarded** xD

Comment: "please use your whole language options!" seems to be an explicit request to risk the program deleting important files.

Comment: @Peter Taylor you would then have to sanitize your program to prevent this risk. This term means that your program should mind using arrays, lists and loops, executing file access would be to much... I will rework the challenge so that the problem is more understandable in scope and restrictions!

Comment: It is required that the language where the digitsums function is expressed to be the same as the language where the genetic algorithm is expressed? It looks that yes, but I just want to be sure of that (or be sure that it is not).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## C#

Almost entirely random and raw assembly solution. As far as C# and pretty much any other platform goes, this is as low level as possible. Luckily, C# allows you to define methods during runtime in IL (IL is intermediate language, the byte-code of .NET, similar to assembly). The only limitation of this code is that I chose some opcodes (out of hundreds) with an arbitrary distribution which would be necessary for the perfect solution. If we allow all opcodes, chances of a working program are slim to none, so this is necessary (as you can imagine, there are many many ways that random assembly instructions can crash, but luckily, they don't bring down the whole program in .NET). Other than the range of possible opcodes, it's completely random slicing and dicing IL opcodes without any kind of hinting. I am pretty surprised but this actually seems to work, some generated programs do not crash and do produce results!

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection.Emit;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;

namespace codegolf
{
    class Program
    {
        // decompile this into IL to find out the opcodes needed for the perfect algo
        static int digitsumbest(int i)
        {
            var ret = 0;
            while (i > 0)
            {
                ret += i % 10;
                i /= 10;
            }
            return ret;
        }

        delegate int digitsumdelegate(int num);

        static Thread bgthread;

        // actually runs the generated code for one index
        // it is invoked in a background thread, which we save so that it can be aborted in case of an infinite loop
        static int run(digitsumdelegate del, int num)
        {
            bgthread = Thread.CurrentThread;
            try
            {
                return del(num);
            }
            catch (ThreadAbortException)
            {
                bgthread = null;
                throw;
            }
        }

        // evaluates a generated code for some inputs and calculates an error level
        // also supports a full run with logging
        static long evaluate(digitsumdelegate del, TextWriter sw)
        {
            var error = 0L;

            List<int> numbers;
            if (sw == null) // quick evaluation
                numbers = Enumerable.Range(1, 30).Concat(Enumerable.Range(1, 70).Select(x => 5000 + x * 31)).ToList();
            else // full run
                numbers = Enumerable.Range(1, 9999).ToList();

            foreach (var num in numbers)
            {
                try
                {
                    Func<digitsumdelegate, int, int> f = run;
                    bgthread = null;
                    var iar = f.BeginInvoke(del, num, null, null);
                    if (!iar.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(10))
                    {
                        bgthread.Abort();
                        while (bgthread != null) ;
                        throw new Exception("timeout");
                    }
                    var result = f.EndInvoke(iar);
                    if (sw != null)
                        sw.WriteLine("{0};{1};{2};", num, digitsumbest(num), result);
                    var diff = result == 0 ? 15 : (result - digitsumbest(num));
                    if (diff > 50 || diff < -50)
                        diff = 50;
                    error += diff * diff;
                }
                catch (InvalidProgramException)
                {
                    // invalid IL code, happens a lot, so let's make a shortcut
                    if (sw != null)
                        sw.WriteLine("invalid program");
                    return numbers.Count * (50 * 50) + 1;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    if (sw != null)
                        sw.WriteLine("{0};{1};;{2}", num, digitsumbest(num), ex.Message);
                    error += 50 * 50;
                }
            }
            return error;
        }

        // generates code from the given byte array
        static digitsumdelegate emit(byte[] ops)
        {
            var dm = new DynamicMethod("w", typeof(int), new[] { typeof(int) });
            var ilg = dm.GetILGenerator();
            var loc = ilg.DeclareLocal(typeof(int));

            // to support jumping anywhere, we will assign a label to every single opcode
            var labels = Enumerable.Range(0, ops.Length).Select(x => ilg.DefineLabel()).ToArray();

            for (var i = 0; i < ops.Length; i++)
            {
                ilg.MarkLabel(labels[i]);

                // 3 types of jumps with 23 distribution each, 11 types of other opcodes with 17 distribution each = all 256 possibilities
                // the opcodes were chosen based on the hand-coded working solution
                var c = ops[i];
                if (c < 23)
                    ilg.Emit(OpCodes.Br_S, labels[(i + 1 + c) % labels.Length]);
                else if (c < 46)
                    ilg.Emit(OpCodes.Bgt_S, labels[(i + 1 + c - 23) % labels.Length]);
                else if (c < 69)
                    ilg.Emit(OpCodes.Bge_S, labels[(i + 1 + c - 46) % labels.Length]);
                else if (c < 86)
                    ilg.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4, c - 70); // stack: +1
                else if (c < 103)
                    ilg.Emit(OpCodes.Dup); // stack: +1
                else if (c < 120)
                    ilg.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0); // stack: +1
                else if (c < 137)
                    ilg.Emit(OpCodes.Starg_S, 0); // stack: -1
                else if (c < 154)
                    ilg.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc, loc); // stack: +1
                else if (c < 171)
                    ilg.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc, loc); // stack: -1
                else if (c < 188)
                    ilg.Emit(OpCodes.Mul); // stack: -1
                else if (c < 205)
                    ilg.Emit(OpCodes.Div); // stack: -1
                else if (c < 222)
                    ilg.Emit(OpCodes.Rem); // stack: -1
                else if (c < 239)
                    ilg.Emit(OpCodes.Add); // stack: -1
                else
                    ilg.Emit(OpCodes.Sub); // stack: -1
            }

            ilg.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
            return (digitsumdelegate)dm.CreateDelegate(typeof(digitsumdelegate));
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().PriorityClass = ProcessPriorityClass.Idle;

            var rnd = new Random();

            // the first list is just 10 small random ones
            var best = new List<byte[]>();
            for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                var initial = new byte[5];
                for (var j = 0; j < initial.Length; j++)
                    initial[j] = (byte)rnd.Next(256);
                best.Add(initial);
            }

            // load the best result from the previous run, if it exists
            if (File.Exists("best.txt"))
                best[0] = File.ReadAllLines("best.txt").Select(x => byte.Parse(x)).ToArray();

            var stop = false;

            // handle nice stopping with ctrl-c
            Console.CancelKeyPress += (s, e) =>
            {
                stop = true;
                e.Cancel = true;
            };

            while (!stop)
            {
                var candidates = new List<byte[]>();

                // leave the 10 best arrays, plus generate 9 consecutive mutations for each of them = 100 candidates
                for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                {
                    var s = best[i];
                    candidates.Add(s);
                    for (var j = 0; j < 9; j++)
                    {
                        // the optimal solution is about 20 opcodes, we keep the program length between 15 and 40
                        switch (rnd.Next(s.Length >= 40 ? 2 : 0, s.Length <= 15 ? 3 : 5))
                        {
                            case 0: // insert
                            case 1:
                                var c = new byte[s.Length + 1];
                                var idx = rnd.Next(0, s.Length);
                                Array.Copy(s, 0, c, 0, idx);
                                c[idx] = (byte)rnd.Next(256);
                                Array.Copy(s, idx, c, idx + 1, s.Length - idx);
                                candidates.Add(c);
                                s = c;
                                break;
                            case 2: // change
                                c = (byte[])s.Clone();
                                idx = rnd.Next(0, s.Length);
                                c[idx] = (byte)rnd.Next(256);
                                candidates.Add(c);
                                s = c;
                                break;
                            case 3: // remove
                            case 4: // remove
                                c = new byte[s.Length - 1];
                                idx = rnd.Next(0, s.Length);
                                Array.Copy(s, 0, c, 0, idx);
                                Array.Copy(s, idx + 1, c, idx, s.Length - idx - 1);
                                candidates.Add(c);
                                s = c;
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }

                // score the candidates and select the best 10
                var scores = Enumerable.Range(0, 100).ToDictionary(i => i, i => evaluate(emit(candidates[i]), null));
                var bestidxes = scores.OrderBy(x => x.Value).Take(10).Select(x => x.Key).ToList();
                Console.WriteLine("best score so far: {0}", scores[bestidxes[0]]);
                best = bestidxes.Select(i => candidates[i]).ToList();
            }

            // output the code of the best solution
            using (var sw = new StreamWriter("best.txt"))
            {
                foreach (var b in best[0])
                    sw.WriteLine(b);
            }

            // create a CSV file with the best solution
            using (var sw = new StreamWriter("best.csv"))
            {
                sw.WriteLine("index;actual;generated;error");
                evaluate(emit(best[0]), sw);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Sorry I have no results so far because even with testing for 1..99 (instead of 1..9999) is pretty slow and I am too tired. Will get back to you tomorrow.

EDIT: I finished the program and tweaked it a lot. Now, if you press CTRL-C, it will finish the current run and output the results in files. Currently, the only viable solutions it produces are programs which always return a constant number. I'm starting to think that the chances of a more advanced working program are astronomically small. Anyway I will keep it running for some time.

EDIT: I keep tweaking the algorithm, it's a perfect toy for a geek like me. I once saw a generated program which actually did some random math and didn't always return a constant number. It would be awesome to run it on a few million CPU's at once :). Will keep running it.

EDIT: Here's the result of some completely random math. It jumps around and stays at 17 for the rest of the indices. It won't become conscious anytime soon.

[image]

EDIT: It's getting more complicated. Of course, as you would expect, it looks nothing like the proper digitsum algorithm, but it's trying hard. Look, a computer generated assembly program!

[image]

Comment: Looks very cool! I will look at your code tomorrow!

Comment: I actually tried a similar approach, and am also fighting hard with a good evaluation function. I also get stuck in local maxima (stuck in solutions, which return correct for 1..19, using fancy modulu operations). Up for you anyway!

PS: in order to get out of a local maximum, I'll try to introduce radical mutations occasionally, and let them develop (in a separate universe, maybe) for a while to be not immediately shot down by the others... (kind of like south america drifting from africa and developing different species ;-)

Answer (score 3):

## C#

This might not be completeley what you envisioned, but this is the best I could do right now. (At least with C# and CodeDom).

So how it works:

1. It calculates the digitsum base 2 (the base wasn't specified in the statement)
2. It tries to generate an expression with a lot of terms that look like `((i & v1) >> v2)`. These terms will be the genes that will be mutated through the run.
3. The fitness function simply compares the values with a pre-calculated array, and uses the sum of the absolute value of the differences. This means a 0 value means we have arrived to the solution, and the less the value the fitter the solution.

The code:

```cs
using System;
using System.CodeDom;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using Microsoft.CSharp;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Evol
{
    class MainClass
    {
        const int BASE = 2;
        static int[] correctValues;
        static List<Evolution> values = new List<Evolution>();

        public static CodeCompileUnit generateCompileUnit(CodeStatementCollection statements) {
            CodeCompileUnit compileUnit = new CodeCompileUnit();
            CodeNamespace samples = new CodeNamespace("CodeGolf");
            compileUnit.Namespaces.Add(samples);
            samples.Imports.Add(new CodeNamespaceImport("System"));
            CodeTypeDeclaration digitSumClass = new CodeTypeDeclaration("DigitSum");
            samples.Types.Add(digitSumClass);
            CodeMemberMethod method = new CodeMemberMethod();
            method.Name = "digitsum";
            method.Attributes = MemberAttributes.Public | MemberAttributes.Static;
            method.ReturnType = new CodeTypeReference (typeof(int));
            method.Parameters.Add (new CodeParameterDeclarationExpression (typeof(int), "i"));
            method.Statements.AddRange (statements);
            digitSumClass.Members.Add(method);
            return compileUnit;
        }

        public static long CompileAndInvoke(CodeStatementCollection statements, bool printCode) {
            CompilerParameters cp = new CompilerParameters();
            cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add( "System.dll" );
            cp.GenerateInMemory = true;
            CodeGeneratorOptions cgo = new CodeGeneratorOptions ();
            CodeDomProvider cpd = new CSharpCodeProvider ();
            CodeCompileUnit cu = generateCompileUnit (statements);
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            cpd.GenerateCodeFromCompileUnit(cu, sw, cgo);
            if (printCode) {
                System.Console.WriteLine (sw.ToString ());
            }

            var result = cpd.CompileAssemblyFromDom (cp, cu);

            if (result.Errors.Count != 0) {
                return -1;
            } else {
                var assembly = result.CompiledAssembly;
                var type = assembly.GetType ("CodeGolf.DigitSum");
                var method = type.GetMethod ("digitsum");
                long fitness = CalcFitness (method);
                return fitness;
            }
        }

        public static long CalcFitness(MethodInfo method) {
            long result = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < correctValues.Length; i++) {
                int r = (int)method.Invoke (null, new Object[] { i });
                result += Math.Abs (r - correctValues[i]);
            }
            return result;
        }

        public static CodeStatementCollection generateCodeDomFromString (Term[] terms) {
            CodeStatementCollection statements = new CodeStatementCollection ();
            CodeExpression expression = null;
            foreach (Term term in terms) {
                CodeExpression inner = new CodeArgumentReferenceExpression ("i");
                if (term.and.HasValue) {
                    inner = new CodeBinaryOperatorExpression (inner, CodeBinaryOperatorType.BitwiseAnd, new CodePrimitiveExpression(term.and.Value));
                }
                if (term.shift.HasValue) {
                    inner = new CodeBinaryOperatorExpression (inner, CodeBinaryOperatorType.Divide, new CodePrimitiveExpression(Math.Pow (2, term.shift.Value)));
                }
                if (expression == null) {
                    expression = inner;
                } else {
                    expression = new CodeBinaryOperatorExpression (expression, CodeBinaryOperatorType.Add, inner);
                }
            }
            statements.Add (new CodeMethodReturnStatement (expression));
            return statements;
        }


        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            correctValues = new int[10001];
            for (int i = 0; i < correctValues.Length; i++) {
                int result = 0;
                int num = i;
                while (num != 0) {
                    result += num % BASE;
                    num /= BASE;
                }
                correctValues [i] = result;
            }
            values.Add (new Evolution (new Term[] { new Term (null, null) }));
            Random rnd = new Random ();
            while (true) {
                // run old generation
                foreach (var val in values) {
                    CodeStatementCollection stat = generateCodeDomFromString (val.term);
                    long fitness = CompileAndInvoke (stat, false);
                    val.score = fitness;
                    System.Console.WriteLine ("Fitness: {0}", fitness);
                }
                Evolution best = values.Aggregate ((i1, i2) => i1.score < i2.score ? i1 : i2);
                CodeStatementCollection bestcoll = generateCodeDomFromString (best.term);
                CompileAndInvoke (bestcoll, true);
                System.Console.WriteLine ("Best fitness for this run: {0}", best.score);

                if (best.score == 0)
                    break;

                // generate new generation
                List<Evolution> top = values.OrderBy (i => i.score).Take (3).ToList();
                values = new List<Evolution> ();
                foreach (var e in top) {
                    values.Add (e);
                    if (e.term.Length < 16) {
                        Term[] newTerm = new Term[e.term.Length + 1];
                        for (int i = 0; i < e.term.Length; i++) {
                            newTerm [i] = e.term [i];
                        }
                        int rrr = rnd.Next (0, 17);
                        newTerm [e.term.Length] = new Term ((int)Math.Pow(2,rrr), rrr);
                        values.Add (new Evolution (newTerm));
                    }
                    {
                        int r = rnd.Next (0, e.term.Length);
                        Term[] newTerm = (Term[])e.term.Clone ();
                        int rrr = rnd.Next (0, 17);
                        newTerm [r] = new Term ((int)Math.Pow(2,rrr), rrr);
                        values.Add (new Evolution (newTerm));
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public struct Term {
            public int? and;
            public int? shift;

            public Term(int? and, int? shift) {
                if (and!=0) {
                    this.and = and;
                } else this.and = null;
                if (shift!=0) {
                    this.shift = shift;
                } else this.shift=null;
            }
        }

        public class Evolution {
            public Term[] term;
            public long score;

            public Evolution(Term[] term) {
                this.term = term;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Tested on OSX with Mono C# compiler version 3.2.6.0.

At each iteration it prints the fitness value of the current calculation. At the end it will print the best solution along with its fitness. The loop will run until one of the results have a fitness value of 0.

This is how it starts:

```cs
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  <autogenerated>
//      This code was generated by a tool.
//      Mono Runtime Version: 4.0.30319.17020
// 
//      Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if 
//      the code is regenerated.
//  </autogenerated>
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace CodeGolf {
    using System;


    public class DigitSum {

        public static int digitsum(int i) {
            return i;
        }
    }
}

Best fitness for this run: 49940387
```

And after a while (takes around 30 minutes), this is how it ends (showing the last and almost last iteration):

```cs
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  <autogenerated>
//      This code was generated by a tool.
//      Mono Runtime Version: 4.0.30319.17020
// 
//      Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if 
//      the code is regenerated.
//  </autogenerated>
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace CodeGolf {
    using System;


    public class DigitSum {

        public static int digitsum(int i) {
            return ((((((((((((((((i & 4096) / 4096) + ((i & 16) / 16)) + ((i & 32) / 32)) + ((i & 128) / 128)) + ((i & 65536) / 65536)) + ((i & 1024) / 1024)) + ((i & 8) / 8)) + ((i & 2) / 2)) + ((i & 512) / 512)) + ((i & 4) / 4)) + (i & 1)) + ((i & 256) / 256)) + ((i & 128) / 128)) + ((i & 8192) / 8192)) + ((i & 2048) / 2048));
        }
    }
}

Best fitness for this run: 4992
Fitness: 4992
Fitness: 7040
Fitness: 4993
Fitness: 4992
Fitness: 0
Fitness: 4992
Fitness: 4992
Fitness: 7496
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  <autogenerated>
//      This code was generated by a tool.
//      Mono Runtime Version: 4.0.30319.17020
// 
//      Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if 
//      the code is regenerated.
//  </autogenerated>
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace CodeGolf {
    using System;


    public class DigitSum {

        public static int digitsum(int i) {
            return (((((((((((((((((i & 4096) / 4096) + ((i & 16) / 16)) + ((i & 32) / 32)) + ((i & 64) / 64)) + ((i & 32768) / 32768)) + ((i & 1024) / 1024)) + ((i & 8) / 8)) + ((i & 2) / 2)) + ((i & 512) / 512)) + ((i & 4) / 4)) + (i & 1)) + ((i & 256) / 256)) + ((i & 128) / 128)) + ((i & 8192) / 8192)) + ((i & 2048) / 2048)) + ((i & 32768) / 32768));
        }
    }
}

Best fitness for this run: 0
```

Notes:

1. CodeDOM doesn't support the left shift operator so instead of `a >> b` I'm using `a / 2^b`
2. The initial iteration is just a `return i;` as required by the problem.
3. In the first few iterations priority is given to adding new terms (genes) to the sum. Later there is more priority in changing values (mutation) in terms randomly.
4. I'm generating terms that look like `i & a >> a` instead of `i & a >> b`, as in the latter case the evolution was simply too slow to be practical.
5. This is also why the solution is limited to finding an answer in the form `return (i&a>>b)+(i&c>>d)+...`, as any other kind (like trying to generate a "proper" code, with loops, assignments, condition checks, etc.) would simply converge too slowly. Also this way it is very easy to define the genes (each of the term), and is very easy to mutate them.
6. This is also the reason why I'm adding the digits in base 2 (the base wasn't specified in the problem statement, so I consider this fine). A base 10 solution would've been just to slow, and also it would've been really hard to define the actual genes. Adding a loop would also mean that you have to manage the running code, and find a possible way to kill it, before it enters a potentially infinite loop.
7. Genes are only mutated, there is no crossover in this solution. I don't know whether adding that would speed up the evolution process or not.
8. The solution is only tested for numbers `0..10000` (if you check the found solution you can see that it won't work for numbers larger than 16384)
9. The whole evolution process [can be checked at this gist.](https://gist.github.com/sztupy/9084074)

Answer (score 3):

### Javascript

Well, I got some floating point precision issue with my answer - that can probably be solved using a BigDecimal library - when input numbers are larger than `55`.
Yes, that's far from `10000` so I don't expect to win but still an interesting method based on [this topic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/405609/is-it-possible-to-find-function-that-contains-every-given-point).
It compute a [polynomial interpolation] (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_interpolation) based on a set of points, so it use only multiplication, division and addition, no modulo or bitwise operators.

```
//used to compute real values
function correct(i) {
  var s = i.toString();
  var o=0;
  for (var i=0; i<s.length; i++) {
    o+=parseInt(s[i]);
  }
  return o;
}

function digitsum(i){return i}
//can be replaced by anything like :
//function digitsum(i){return (Math.sin(i*i)+2*Math.sqrt(i)))}

for (var j=0; j<60; j++) {
  var p = correct(j+1)-digitsum(j+1);
  if (p != 0) {
    var g='Math.round(1';
    for (var k=0; k<j+1; k++) {
      g+='*((i-'+k+')/'+(j+1-k)+')';
    }
    g+=')';
    eval(digitsum.toString().replace(/{return (.*)}/, function (m,v) {
      return "{return "+v+"+"+p+"*"+g+"}";
    }));
  }
}

console.log(digitsum);
```

Output function :

```
function digitsum(i){return i+-9*Math.round(1*((i-0)/10)*((i-1)/9)*((i-2)/8)*((i-3)/7)*((i-4)/6)*((i-5)/5)*((i-6)/4)*((i-7)/3)*((i-8)/2)*((i-9)/1))+90*Math.round(1*((i-0)/11)*((i-1)/10)*((i-2)/9)*((i-3)/8)*((i-4)/7)*((i-5)/6)*((i-6)/5)*((i-7)/4)*((i-8)/3)*((i-9)/2)*((i-10)/1))+-495*Math.round(1*((i-0)/12)*((i-1)/11)*((i-2)/10)*((i-3)/9)*((i-4)/8)*((i-5)/7)*((i-6)/6)*((i-7)/5)*((i-8)/4)*((i-9)/3)*((i-10)/2)*((i-11)/1))+1980*Math.round(1*((i-0)/13)*((i-1)/12)*((i-2)/11)*((i-3)/10)*((i-4)/9)*((i-5)/8)*((i-6)/7)*((i-7)/6)*((i-8)/5)*((i-9)/4)*((i-10)/3)*((i-11)/2)*((i-12)/1))+-6435*Math.round(1*((i-0)/14)*((i-1)/13)*((i-2)/12)*((i-3)/11)*((i-4)/10)*((i-5)/9)*((i-6)/8)*((i-7)/7)*((i-8)/6)*((i-9)/5)*((i-10)/4)*((i-11)/3)*((i-12)/2)*((i-13)/1))+18018*Math.round(1*((i-0)/15)*((i-1)/14)*((i-2)/13)*((i-3)/12)*((i-4)/11)*((i-5)/10)*((i-6)/9)*((i-7)/8)*((i-8)/7)*((i-9)/6)*((i-10)/5)*((i-11)/4)*((i-12)/3)*((i-13)/2)*((i-14)/1))+-45045*Math.round(1*((i-0)/16)*((i-1)/15)*((i-2)/14)*((i-3)/13)*((i-4)/12)*((i-5)/11)*((i-6)/10)*((i-7)/9)*((i-8)/8)*((i-9)/7)*((i-10)/6)*((i-11)/5)*((i-12)/4)*((i-13)/3)*((i-14)/2)*((i-15)/1))+102960*Math.round(1*((i-0)/17)*((i-1)/16)*((i-2)/15)*((i-3)/14)*((i-4)/13)*((i-5)/12)*((i-6)/11)*((i-7)/10)*((i-8)/9)*((i-9)/8)*((i-10)/7)*((i-11)/6)*((i-12)/5)*((i-13)/4)*((i-14)/3)*((i-15)/2)*((i-16)/1))+-218790*Math.round(1*((i-0)/18)*((i-1)/17)*((i-2)/16)*((i-3)/15)*((i-4)/14)*((i-5)/13)*((i-6)/12)*((i-7)/11)*((i-8)/10)*((i-9)/9)*((i-10)/8)*((i-11)/7)*((i-12)/6)*((i-13)/5)*((i-14)/4)*((i-15)/3)*((i-16)/2)*((i-17)/1))+437580*Math.round(1*((i-0)/19)*((i-1)/18)*((i-2)/17)*((i-3)/16)*((i-4)/15)*((i-5)/14)*((i-6)/13)*((i-7)/12)*((i-8)/11)*((i-9)/10)*((i-10)/9)*((i-11)/8)*((i-12)/7)*((i-13)/6)*((i-14)/5)*((i-15)/4)*((i-16)/3)*((i-17)/2)*((i-18)/1))+-831411*Math.round(1*((i-0)/20)*((i-1)/19)*((i-2)/18)*((i-3)/17)*((i-4)/16)*((i-5)/15)*((i-6)/14)*((i-7)/13)*((i-8)/12)*((i-9)/11)*((i-10)/10)*((i-11)/9)*((i-12)/8)*((i-13)/7)*((i-14)/6)*((i-15)/5)*((i-16)/4)*((i-17)/3)*((i-18)/2)*((i-19)/1))+1511820*Math.round(1*((i-0)/21)*((i-1)/20)*((i-2)/19)*((i-3)/18)*((i-4)/17)*((i-5)/16)*((i-6)/15)*((i-7)/14)*((i-8)/13)*((i-9)/12)*((i-10)/11)*((i-11)/10)*((i-12)/9)*((i-13)/8)*((i-14)/7)*((i-15)/6)*((i-16)/5)*((i-17)/4)*((i-18)/3)*((i-19)/2)*((i-20)/1))+-2647260*Math.round(1*((i-0)/22)*((i-1)/21)*((i-2)/20)*((i-3)/19)*((i-4)/18)*((i-5)/17)*((i-6)/16)*((i-7)/15)*((i-8)/14)*((i-9)/13)*((i-10)/12)*((i-11)/11)*((i-12)/10)*((i-13)/9)*((i-14)/8)*((i-15)/7)*((i-16)/6)*((i-17)/5)*((i-18)/4)*((i-19)/3)*((i-20)/2)*((i-21)/1))+4490640*Math.round(1*((i-0)/23)*((i-1)/22)*((i-2)/21)*((i-3)/20)*((i-4)/19)*((i-5)/18)*((i-6)/17)*((i-7)/16)*((i-8)/15)*((i-9)/14)*((i-10)/13)*((i-11)/12)*((i-12)/11)*((i-13)/10)*((i-14)/9)*((i-15)/8)*((i-16)/7)*((i-17)/6)*((i-18)/5)*((i-19)/4)*((i-20)/3)*((i-21)/2)*((i-22)/1))+-7434405*Math.round(1*((i-0)/24)*((i-1)/23)*((i-2)/22)*((i-3)/21)*((i-4)/20)*((i-5)/19)*((i-6)/18)*((i-7)/17)*((i-8)/16)*((i-9)/15)*((i-10)/14)*((i-11)/13)*((i-12)/12)*((i-13)/11)*((i-14)/10)*((i-15)/9)*((i-16)/8)*((i-17)/7)*((i-18)/6)*((i-19)/5)*((i-20)/4)*((i-21)/3)*((i-22)/2)*((i-23)/1))+12150072*Math.round(1*((i-0)/25)*((i-1)/24)*((i-2)/23)*((i-3)/22)*((i-4)/21)*((i-5)/20)*((i-6)/19)*((i-7)/18)*((i-8)/17)*((i-9)/16)*((i-10)/15)*((i-11)/14)*((i-12)/13)*((i-13)/12)*((i-14)/11)*((i-15)/10)*((i-16)/9)*((i-17)/8)*((i-18)/7)*((i-19)/6)*((i-20)/5)*((i-21)/4)*((i-22)/3)*((i-23)/2)*((i-24)/1))+-19980675*Math.round(1*((i-0)/26)*((i-1)/25)*((i-2)/24)*((i-3)/23)*((i-4)/22)*((i-5)/21)*((i-6)/20)*((i-7)/19)*((i-8)/18)*((i-9)/17)*((i-10)/16)*((i-11)/15)*((i-12)/14)*((i-13)/13)*((i-14)/12)*((i-15)/11)*((i-16)/10)*((i-17)/9)*((i-18)/8)*((i-19)/7)*((i-20)/6)*((i-21)/5)*((i-22)/4)*((i-23)/3)*((i-24)/2)*((i-25)/1))+34041150*Math.round(1*((i-0)/27)*((i-1)/26)*((i-2)/25)*((i-3)/24)*((i-4)/23)*((i-5)/22)*((i-6)/21)*((i-7)/20)*((i-8)/19)*((i-9)/18)*((i-10)/17)*((i-11)/16)*((i-12)/15)*((i-13)/14)*((i-14)/13)*((i-15)/12)*((i-16)/11)*((i-17)/10)*((i-18)/9)*((i-19)/8)*((i-20)/7)*((i-21)/6)*((i-22)/5)*((i-23)/4)*((i-24)/3)*((i-25)/2)*((i-26)/1))+-62162100*Math.round(1*((i-0)/28)*((i-1)/27)*((i-2)/26)*((i-3)/25)*((i-4)/24)*((i-5)/23)*((i-6)/22)*((i-7)/21)*((i-8)/20)*((i-9)/19)*((i-10)/18)*((i-11)/17)*((i-12)/16)*((i-13)/15)*((i-14)/14)*((i-15)/13)*((i-16)/12)*((i-17)/11)*((i-18)/10)*((i-19)/9)*((i-20)/8)*((i-21)/7)*((i-22)/6)*((i-23)/5)*((i-24)/4)*((i-25)/3)*((i-26)/2)*((i-27)/1))+124324200*Math.round(1*((i-0)/29)*((i-1)/28)*((i-2)/27)*((i-3)/26)*((i-4)/25)*((i-5)/24)*((i-6)/23)*((i-7)/22)*((i-8)/21)*((i-9)/20)*((i-10)/19)*((i-11)/18)*((i-12)/17)*((i-13)/16)*((i-14)/15)*((i-15)/14)*((i-16)/13)*((i-17)/12)*((i-18)/11)*((i-19)/10)*((i-20)/9)*((i-21)/8)*((i-22)/7)*((i-23)/6)*((i-24)/5)*((i-25)/4)*((i-26)/3)*((i-27)/2)*((i-28)/1))+-270405144*Math.round(1*((i-0)/30)*((i-1)/29)*((i-2)/28)*((i-3)/27)*((i-4)/26)*((i-5)/25)*((i-6)/24)*((i-7)/23)*((i-8)/22)*((i-9)/21)*((i-10)/20)*((i-11)/19)*((i-12)/18)*((i-13)/17)*((i-14)/16)*((i-15)/15)*((i-16)/14)*((i-17)/13)*((i-18)/12)*((i-19)/11)*((i-20)/10)*((i-21)/9)*((i-22)/8)*((i-23)/7)*((i-24)/6)*((i-25)/5)*((i-26)/4)*((i-27)/3)*((i-28)/2)*((i-29)/1))+620410320*Math.round(1*((i-0)/31)*((i-1)/30)*((i-2)/29)*((i-3)/28)*((i-4)/27)*((i-5)/26)*((i-6)/25)*((i-7)/24)*((i-8)/23)*((i-9)/22)*((i-10)/21)*((i-11)/20)*((i-12)/19)*((i-13)/18)*((i-14)/17)*((i-15)/16)*((i-16)/15)*((i-17)/14)*((i-18)/13)*((i-19)/12)*((i-20)/11)*((i-21)/10)*((i-22)/9)*((i-23)/8)*((i-24)/7)*((i-25)/6)*((i-26)/5)*((i-27)/4)*((i-28)/3)*((i-29)/2)*((i-30)/1))+-1451529585*Math.round(1*((i-0)/32)*((i-1)/31)*((i-2)/30)*((i-3)/29)*((i-4)/28)*((i-5)/27)*((i-6)/26)*((i-7)/25)*((i-8)/24)*((i-9)/23)*((i-10)/22)*((i-11)/21)*((i-12)/20)*((i-13)/19)*((i-14)/18)*((i-15)/17)*((i-16)/16)*((i-17)/15)*((i-18)/14)*((i-19)/13)*((i-20)/12)*((i-21)/11)*((i-22)/10)*((i-23)/9)*((i-24)/8)*((i-25)/7)*((i-26)/6)*((i-27)/5)*((i-28)/4)*((i-29)/3)*((i-30)/2)*((i-31)/1))+3378846240*Math.round(1*((i-0)/33)*((i-1)/32)*((i-2)/31)*((i-3)/30)*((i-4)/29)*((i-5)/28)*((i-6)/27)*((i-7)/26)*((i-8)/25)*((i-9)/24)*((i-10)/23)*((i-11)/22)*((i-12)/21)*((i-13)/20)*((i-14)/19)*((i-15)/18)*((i-16)/17)*((i-17)/16)*((i-18)/15)*((i-19)/14)*((i-20)/13)*((i-21)/12)*((i-22)/11)*((i-23)/10)*((i-24)/9)*((i-25)/8)*((i-26)/7)*((i-27)/6)*((i-28)/5)*((i-29)/4)*((i-30)/3)*((i-31)/2)*((i-32)/1))+-7716754980*Math.round(1*((i-0)/34)*((i-1)/33)*((i-2)/32)*((i-3)/31)*((i-4)/30)*((i-5)/29)*((i-6)/28)*((i-7)/27)*((i-8)/26)*((i-9)/25)*((i-10)/24)*((i-11)/23)*((i-12)/22)*((i-13)/21)*((i-14)/20)*((i-15)/19)*((i-16)/18)*((i-17)/17)*((i-18)/16)*((i-19)/15)*((i-20)/14)*((i-21)/13)*((i-22)/12)*((i-23)/11)*((i-24)/10)*((i-25)/9)*((i-26)/8)*((i-27)/7)*((i-28)/6)*((i-29)/5)*((i-30)/4)*((i-31)/3)*((i-32)/2)*((i-33)/1))+17178273288*Math.round(1*((i-0)/35)*((i-1)/34)*((i-2)/33)*((i-3)/32)*((i-4)/31)*((i-5)/30)*((i-6)/29)*((i-7)/28)*((i-8)/27)*((i-9)/26)*((i-10)/25)*((i-11)/24)*((i-12)/23)*((i-13)/22)*((i-14)/21)*((i-15)/20)*((i-16)/19)*((i-17)/18)*((i-18)/17)*((i-19)/16)*((i-20)/15)*((i-21)/14)*((i-22)/13)*((i-23)/12)*((i-24)/11)*((i-25)/10)*((i-26)/9)*((i-27)/8)*((i-28)/7)*((i-29)/6)*((i-30)/5)*((i-31)/4)*((i-32)/3)*((i-33)/2)*((i-34)/1))+-37189436130*Math.round(1*((i-0)/36)*((i-1)/35)*((i-2)/34)*((i-3)/33)*((i-4)/32)*((i-5)/31)*((i-6)/30)*((i-7)/29)*((i-8)/28)*((i-9)/27)*((i-10)/26)*((i-11)/25)*((i-12)/24)*((i-13)/23)*((i-14)/22)*((i-15)/21)*((i-16)/20)*((i-17)/19)*((i-18)/18)*((i-19)/17)*((i-20)/16)*((i-21)/15)*((i-22)/14)*((i-23)/13)*((i-24)/12)*((i-25)/11)*((i-26)/10)*((i-27)/9)*((i-28)/8)*((i-29)/7)*((i-30)/6)*((i-31)/5)*((i-32)/4)*((i-33)/3)*((i-34)/2)*((i-35)/1))+78299888041*Math.round(1*((i-0)/37)*((i-1)/36)*((i-2)/35)*((i-3)/34)*((i-4)/33)*((i-5)/32)*((i-6)/31)*((i-7)/30)*((i-8)/29)*((i-9)/28)*((i-10)/27)*((i-11)/26)*((i-12)/25)*((i-13)/24)*((i-14)/23)*((i-15)/22)*((i-16)/21)*((i-17)/20)*((i-18)/19)*((i-19)/18)*((i-20)/17)*((i-21)/16)*((i-22)/15)*((i-23)/14)*((i-24)/13)*((i-25)/12)*((i-26)/11)*((i-27)/10)*((i-28)/9)*((i-29)/8)*((i-30)/7)*((i-31)/6)*((i-32)/5)*((i-33)/4)*((i-34)/3)*((i-35)/2)*((i-36)/1))+-160520791904*Math.round(1*((i-0)/38)*((i-1)/37)*((i-2)/36)*((i-3)/35)*((i-4)/34)*((i-5)/33)*((i-6)/32)*((i-7)/31)*((i-8)/30)*((i-9)/29)*((i-10)/28)*((i-11)/27)*((i-12)/26)*((i-13)/25)*((i-14)/24)*((i-15)/23)*((i-16)/22)*((i-17)/21)*((i-18)/20)*((i-19)/19)*((i-20)/18)*((i-21)/17)*((i-22)/16)*((i-23)/15)*((i-24)/14)*((i-25)/13)*((i-26)/12)*((i-27)/11)*((i-28)/10)*((i-29)/9)*((i-30)/8)*((i-31)/7)*((i-32)/6)*((i-33)/5)*((i-34)/4)*((i-35)/3)*((i-36)/2)*((i-37)/1))+321041584713*Math.round(1*((i-0)/39)*((i-1)/38)*((i-2)/37)*((i-3)/36)*((i-4)/35)*((i-5)/34)*((i-6)/33)*((i-7)/32)*((i-8)/31)*((i-9)/30)*((i-10)/29)*((i-11)/28)*((i-12)/27)*((i-13)/26)*((i-14)/25)*((i-15)/24)*((i-16)/23)*((i-17)/22)*((i-18)/21)*((i-19)/20)*((i-20)/19)*((i-21)/18)*((i-22)/17)*((i-23)/16)*((i-24)/15)*((i-25)/14)*((i-26)/13)*((i-27)/12)*((i-28)/11)*((i-29)/10)*((i-30)/9)*((i-31)/8)*((i-32)/7)*((i-33)/6)*((i-34)/5)*((i-35)/4)*((i-36)/3)*((i-37)/2)*((i-38)/1))+-627938339760*Math.round(1*((i-0)/40)*((i-1)/39)*((i-2)/38)*((i-3)/37)*((i-4)/36)*((i-5)/35)*((i-6)/34)*((i-7)/33)*((i-8)/32)*((i-9)/31)*((i-10)/30)*((i-11)/29)*((i-12)/28)*((i-13)/27)*((i-14)/26)*((i-15)/25)*((i-16)/24)*((i-17)/23)*((i-18)/22)*((i-19)/21)*((i-20)/20)*((i-21)/19)*((i-22)/18)*((i-23)/17)*((i-24)/16)*((i-25)/15)*((i-26)/14)*((i-27)/13)*((i-28)/12)*((i-29)/11)*((i-30)/10)*((i-31)/9)*((i-32)/8)*((i-33)/7)*((i-34)/6)*((i-35)/5)*((i-36)/4)*((i-37)/3)*((i-38)/2)*((i-39)/1))+1204809019815*Math.round(1*((i-0)/41)*((i-1)/40)*((i-2)/39)*((i-3)/38)*((i-4)/37)*((i-5)/36)*((i-6)/35)*((i-7)/34)*((i-8)/33)*((i-9)/32)*((i-10)/31)*((i-11)/30)*((i-12)/29)*((i-13)/28)*((i-14)/27)*((i-15)/26)*((i-16)/25)*((i-17)/24)*((i-18)/23)*((i-19)/22)*((i-20)/21)*((i-21)/20)*((i-22)/19)*((i-23)/18)*((i-24)/17)*((i-25)/16)*((i-26)/15)*((i-27)/14)*((i-28)/13)*((i-29)/12)*((i-30)/11)*((i-31)/10)*((i-32)/9)*((i-33)/8)*((i-34)/7)*((i-35)/6)*((i-36)/5)*((i-37)/4)*((i-38)/3)*((i-39)/2)*((i-40)/1))+-2276206770520*Math.round(1*((i-0)/42)*((i-1)/41)*((i-2)/40)*((i-3)/39)*((i-4)/38)*((i-5)/37)*((i-6)/36)*((i-7)/35)*((i-8)/34)*((i-9)/33)*((i-10)/32)*((i-11)/31)*((i-12)/30)*((i-13)/29)*((i-14)/28)*((i-15)/27)*((i-16)/26)*((i-17)/25)*((i-18)/24)*((i-19)/23)*((i-20)/22)*((i-21)/21)*((i-22)/20)*((i-23)/19)*((i-24)/18)*((i-25)/17)*((i-26)/16)*((i-27)/15)*((i-28)/14)*((i-29)/13)*((i-30)/12)*((i-31)/11)*((i-32)/10)*((i-33)/9)*((i-34)/8)*((i-35)/7)*((i-36)/6)*((i-37)/5)*((i-38)/4)*((i-39)/3)*((i-40)/2)*((i-41)/1))+4254673762574*Math.round(1*((i-0)/43)*((i-1)/42)*((i-2)/41)*((i-3)/40)*((i-4)/39)*((i-5)/38)*((i-6)/37)*((i-7)/36)*((i-8)/35)*((i-9)/34)*((i-10)/33)*((i-11)/32)*((i-12)/31)*((i-13)/30)*((i-14)/29)*((i-15)/28)*((i-16)/27)*((i-17)/26)*((i-18)/25)*((i-19)/24)*((i-20)/23)*((i-21)/22)*((i-22)/21)*((i-23)/20)*((i-24)/19)*((i-25)/18)*((i-26)/17)*((i-27)/16)*((i-28)/15)*((i-29)/14)*((i-30)/13)*((i-31)/12)*((i-32)/11)*((i-33)/10)*((i-34)/9)*((i-35)/8)*((i-36)/7)*((i-37)/6)*((i-38)/5)*((i-39)/4)*((i-40)/3)*((i-41)/2)*((i-42)/1))+-7914840120452*Math.round(1*((i-0)/44)*((i-1)/43)*((i-2)/42)*((i-3)/41)*((i-4)/40)*((i-5)/39)*((i-6)/38)*((i-7)/37)*((i-8)/36)*((i-9)/35)*((i-10)/34)*((i-11)/33)*((i-12)/32)*((i-13)/31)*((i-14)/30)*((i-15)/29)*((i-16)/28)*((i-17)/27)*((i-18)/26)*((i-19)/25)*((i-20)/24)*((i-21)/23)*((i-22)/22)*((i-23)/21)*((i-24)/20)*((i-25)/19)*((i-26)/18)*((i-27)/17)*((i-28)/16)*((i-29)/15)*((i-30)/14)*((i-31)/13)*((i-32)/12)*((i-33)/11)*((i-34)/10)*((i-35)/9)*((i-36)/8)*((i-37)/7)*((i-38)/6)*((i-39)/5)*((i-40)/4)*((i-41)/3)*((i-42)/2)*((i-43)/1))+14755713366633*Math.round(1*((i-0)/45)*((i-1)/44)*((i-2)/43)*((i-3)/42)*((i-4)/41)*((i-5)/40)*((i-6)/39)*((i-7)/38)*((i-8)/37)*((i-9)/36)*((i-10)/35)*((i-11)/34)*((i-12)/33)*((i-13)/32)*((i-14)/31)*((i-15)/30)*((i-16)/29)*((i-17)/28)*((i-18)/27)*((i-19)/26)*((i-20)/25)*((i-21)/24)*((i-22)/23)*((i-23)/22)*((i-24)/21)*((i-25)/20)*((i-26)/19)*((i-27)/18)*((i-28)/17)*((i-29)/16)*((i-30)/15)*((i-31)/14)*((i-32)/13)*((i-33)/12)*((i-34)/11)*((i-35)/10)*((i-36)/9)*((i-37)/8)*((i-38)/7)*((i-39)/6)*((i-40)/5)*((i-41)/4)*((i-42)/3)*((i-43)/2)*((i-44)/1))+-27776520662160*Math.round(1*((i-0)/46)*((i-1)/45)*((i-2)/44)*((i-3)/43)*((i-4)/42)*((i-5)/41)*((i-6)/40)*((i-7)/39)*((i-8)/38)*((i-9)/37)*((i-10)/36)*((i-11)/35)*((i-12)/34)*((i-13)/33)*((i-14)/32)*((i-15)/31)*((i-16)/30)*((i-17)/29)*((i-18)/28)*((i-19)/27)*((i-20)/26)*((i-21)/25)*((i-22)/24)*((i-23)/23)*((i-24)/22)*((i-25)/21)*((i-26)/20)*((i-27)/19)*((i-28)/18)*((i-29)/17)*((i-30)/16)*((i-31)/15)*((i-32)/14)*((i-33)/13)*((i-34)/12)*((i-35)/11)*((i-36)/10)*((i-37)/9)*((i-38)/8)*((i-39)/7)*((i-40)/6)*((i-41)/5)*((i-42)/4)*((i-43)/3)*((i-44)/2)*((i-45)/1))+53164054207611*Math.round(1*((i-0)/47)*((i-1)/46)*((i-2)/45)*((i-3)/44)*((i-4)/43)*((i-5)/42)*((i-6)/41)*((i-7)/40)*((i-8)/39)*((i-9)/38)*((i-10)/37)*((i-11)/36)*((i-12)/35)*((i-13)/34)*((i-14)/33)*((i-15)/32)*((i-16)/31)*((i-17)/30)*((i-18)/29)*((i-19)/28)*((i-20)/27)*((i-21)/26)*((i-22)/25)*((i-23)/24)*((i-24)/23)*((i-25)/22)*((i-26)/21)*((i-27)/20)*((i-28)/19)*((i-29)/18)*((i-30)/17)*((i-31)/16)*((i-32)/15)*((i-33)/14)*((i-34)/13)*((i-35)/12)*((i-36)/11)*((i-37)/10)*((i-38)/9)*((i-39)/8)*((i-40)/7)*((i-41)/6)*((i-42)/5)*((i-43)/4)*((i-44)/3)*((i-45)/2)*((i-46)/1))+-103975831339140*Math.round(1*((i-0)/48)*((i-1)/47)*((i-2)/46)*((i-3)/45)*((i-4)/44)*((i-5)/43)*((i-6)/42)*((i-7)/41)*((i-8)/40)*((i-9)/39)*((i-10)/38)*((i-11)/37)*((i-12)/36)*((i-13)/35)*((i-14)/34)*((i-15)/33)*((i-16)/32)*((i-17)/31)*((i-18)/30)*((i-19)/29)*((i-20)/28)*((i-21)/27)*((i-22)/26)*((i-23)/25)*((i-24)/24)*((i-25)/23)*((i-26)/22)*((i-27)/21)*((i-28)/20)*((i-29)/19)*((i-30)/18)*((i-31)/17)*((i-32)/16)*((i-33)/15)*((i-34)/14)*((i-35)/13)*((i-36)/12)*((i-37)/11)*((i-38)/10)*((i-39)/9)*((i-40)/8)*((i-41)/7)*((i-42)/6)*((i-43)/5)*((i-44)/4)*((i-45)/3)*((i-46)/2)*((i-47)/1))+208138306632137*Math.round(1*((i-0)/49)*((i-1)/48)*((i-2)/47)*((i-3)/46)*((i-4)/45)*((i-5)/44)*((i-6)/43)*((i-7)/42)*((i-8)/41)*((i-9)/40)*((i-10)/39)*((i-11)/38)*((i-12)/37)*((i-13)/36)*((i-14)/35)*((i-15)/34)*((i-16)/33)*((i-17)/32)*((i-18)/31)*((i-19)/30)*((i-20)/29)*((i-21)/28)*((i-22)/27)*((i-23)/26)*((i-24)/25)*((i-25)/24)*((i-26)/23)*((i-27)/22)*((i-28)/21)*((i-29)/20)*((i-30)/19)*((i-31)/18)*((i-32)/17)*((i-33)/16)*((i-34)/15)*((i-35)/14)*((i-36)/13)*((i-37)/12)*((i-38)/11)*((i-39)/10)*((i-40)/9)*((i-41)/8)*((i-42)/7)*((i-43)/6)*((i-44)/5)*((i-45)/4)*((i-46)/3)*((i-47)/2)*((i-48)/1))+-425620349055645*Math.round(1*((i-0)/50)*((i-1)/49)*((i-2)/48)*((i-3)/47)*((i-4)/46)*((i-5)/45)*((i-6)/44)*((i-7)/43)*((i-8)/42)*((i-9)/41)*((i-10)/40)*((i-11)/39)*((i-12)/38)*((i-13)/37)*((i-14)/36)*((i-15)/35)*((i-16)/34)*((i-17)/33)*((i-18)/32)*((i-19)/31)*((i-20)/30)*((i-21)/29)*((i-22)/28)*((i-23)/27)*((i-24)/26)*((i-25)/25)*((i-26)/24)*((i-27)/23)*((i-28)/22)*((i-29)/21)*((i-30)/20)*((i-31)/19)*((i-32)/18)*((i-33)/17)*((i-34)/16)*((i-35)/15)*((i-36)/14)*((i-37)/13)*((i-38)/12)*((i-39)/11)*((i-40)/10)*((i-41)/9)*((i-42)/8)*((i-43)/7)*((i-44)/6)*((i-45)/5)*((i-46)/4)*((i-47)/3)*((i-48)/2)*((i-49)/1))+884722839970606*Math.round(1*((i-0)/51)*((i-1)/50)*((i-2)/49)*((i-3)/48)*((i-4)/47)*((i-5)/46)*((i-6)/45)*((i-7)/44)*((i-8)/43)*((i-9)/42)*((i-10)/41)*((i-11)/40)*((i-12)/39)*((i-13)/38)*((i-14)/37)*((i-15)/36)*((i-16)/35)*((i-17)/34)*((i-18)/33)*((i-19)/32)*((i-20)/31)*((i-21)/30)*((i-22)/29)*((i-23)/28)*((i-24)/27)*((i-25)/26)*((i-26)/25)*((i-27)/24)*((i-28)/23)*((i-29)/22)*((i-30)/21)*((i-31)/20)*((i-32)/19)*((i-33)/18)*((i-34)/17)*((i-35)/16)*((i-36)/15)*((i-37)/14)*((i-38)/13)*((i-39)/12)*((i-40)/11)*((i-41)/10)*((i-42)/9)*((i-43)/8)*((i-44)/7)*((i-45)/6)*((i-46)/5)*((i-47)/4)*((i-48)/3)*((i-49)/2)*((i-50)/1))+-1857183748827153*Math.round(1*((i-0)/52)*((i-1)/51)*((i-2)/50)*((i-3)/49)*((i-4)/48)*((i-5)/47)*((i-6)/46)*((i-7)/45)*((i-8)/44)*((i-9)/43)*((i-10)/42)*((i-11)/41)*((i-12)/40)*((i-13)/39)*((i-14)/38)*((i-15)/37)*((i-16)/36)*((i-17)/35)*((i-18)/34)*((i-19)/33)*((i-20)/32)*((i-21)/31)*((i-22)/30)*((i-23)/29)*((i-24)/28)*((i-25)/27)*((i-26)/26)*((i-27)/25)*((i-28)/24)*((i-29)/23)*((i-30)/22)*((i-31)/21)*((i-32)/20)*((i-33)/19)*((i-34)/18)*((i-35)/17)*((i-36)/16)*((i-37)/15)*((i-38)/14)*((i-39)/13)*((i-40)/12)*((i-41)/11)*((i-42)/10)*((i-43)/9)*((i-44)/8)*((i-45)/7)*((i-46)/6)*((i-47)/5)*((i-48)/4)*((i-49)/3)*((i-50)/2)*((i-51)/1))+3909404796652936*Math.round(1*((i-0)/53)*((i-1)/52)*((i-2)/51)*((i-3)/50)*((i-4)/49)*((i-5)/48)*((i-6)/47)*((i-7)/46)*((i-8)/45)*((i-9)/44)*((i-10)/43)*((i-11)/42)*((i-12)/41)*((i-13)/40)*((i-14)/39)*((i-15)/38)*((i-16)/37)*((i-17)/36)*((i-18)/35)*((i-19)/34)*((i-20)/33)*((i-21)/32)*((i-22)/31)*((i-23)/30)*((i-24)/29)*((i-25)/28)*((i-26)/27)*((i-27)/26)*((i-28)/25)*((i-29)/24)*((i-30)/23)*((i-31)/22)*((i-32)/21)*((i-33)/20)*((i-34)/19)*((i-35)/18)*((i-36)/17)*((i-37)/16)*((i-38)/15)*((i-39)/14)*((i-40)/13)*((i-41)/12)*((i-42)/11)*((i-43)/10)*((i-44)/9)*((i-45)/8)*((i-46)/7)*((i-47)/6)*((i-48)/5)*((i-49)/4)*((i-50)/3)*((i-51)/2)*((i-52)/1))+-8195615777370807*Math.round(1*((i-0)/54)*((i-1)/53)*((i-2)/52)*((i-3)/51)*((i-4)/50)*((i-5)/49)*((i-6)/48)*((i-7)/47)*((i-8)/46)*((i-9)/45)*((i-10)/44)*((i-11)/43)*((i-12)/42)*((i-13)/41)*((i-14)/40)*((i-15)/39)*((i-16)/38)*((i-17)/37)*((i-18)/36)*((i-19)/35)*((i-20)/34)*((i-21)/33)*((i-22)/32)*((i-23)/31)*((i-24)/30)*((i-25)/29)*((i-26)/28)*((i-27)/27)*((i-28)/26)*((i-29)/25)*((i-30)/24)*((i-31)/23)*((i-32)/22)*((i-33)/21)*((i-34)/20)*((i-35)/19)*((i-36)/18)*((i-37)/17)*((i-38)/16)*((i-39)/15)*((i-40)/14)*((i-41)/13)*((i-42)/12)*((i-43)/11)*((i-44)/10)*((i-45)/9)*((i-46)/8)*((i-47)/7)*((i-48)/6)*((i-49)/5)*((i-50)/4)*((i-51)/3)*((i-52)/2)*((i-53)/1))+16994979589974346*Math.round(1*((i-0)/55)*((i-1)/54)*((i-2)/53)*((i-3)/52)*((i-4)/51)*((i-5)/50)*((i-6)/49)*((i-7)/48)*((i-8)/47)*((i-9)/46)*((i-10)/45)*((i-11)/44)*((i-12)/43)*((i-13)/42)*((i-14)/41)*((i-15)/40)*((i-16)/39)*((i-17)/38)*((i-18)/37)*((i-19)/36)*((i-20)/35)*((i-21)/34)*((i-22)/33)*((i-23)/32)*((i-24)/31)*((i-25)/30)*((i-26)/29)*((i-27)/28)*((i-28)/27)*((i-29)/26)*((i-30)/25)*((i-31)/24)*((i-32)/23)*((i-33)/22)*((i-34)/21)*((i-35)/20)*((i-36)/19)*((i-37)/18)*((i-38)/17)*((i-39)/16)*((i-40)/15)*((i-41)/14)*((i-42)/13)*((i-43)/12)*((i-44)/11)*((i-45)/10)*((i-46)/9)*((i-47)/8)*((i-48)/7)*((i-49)/6)*((i-50)/5)*((i-51)/4)*((i-52)/3)*((i-53)/2)*((i-54)/1))+-34598925396029428*Math.round(1*((i-0)/56)*((i-1)/55)*((i-2)/54)*((i-3)/53)*((i-4)/52)*((i-5)/51)*((i-6)/50)*((i-7)/49)*((i-8)/48)*((i-9)/47)*((i-10)/46)*((i-11)/45)*((i-12)/44)*((i-13)/43)*((i-14)/42)*((i-15)/41)*((i-16)/40)*((i-17)/39)*((i-18)/38)*((i-19)/37)*((i-20)/36)*((i-21)/35)*((i-22)/34)*((i-23)/33)*((i-24)/32)*((i-25)/31)*((i-26)/30)*((i-27)/29)*((i-28)/28)*((i-29)/27)*((i-30)/26)*((i-31)/25)*((i-32)/24)*((i-33)/23)*((i-34)/22)*((i-35)/21)*((i-36)/20)*((i-37)/19)*((i-38)/18)*((i-39)/17)*((i-40)/16)*((i-41)/15)*((i-42)/14)*((i-43)/13)*((i-44)/12)*((i-45)/11)*((i-46)/10)*((i-47)/9)*((i-48)/8)*((i-49)/7)*((i-50)/6)*((i-51)/5)*((i-52)/4)*((i-53)/3)*((i-54)/2)*((i-55)/1))+68349348631526670*Math.round(1*((i-0)/57)*((i-1)/56)*((i-2)/55)*((i-3)/54)*((i-4)/53)*((i-5)/52)*((i-6)/51)*((i-7)/50)*((i-8)/49)*((i-9)/48)*((i-10)/47)*((i-11)/46)*((i-12)/45)*((i-13)/44)*((i-14)/43)*((i-15)/42)*((i-16)/41)*((i-17)/40)*((i-18)/39)*((i-19)/38)*((i-20)/37)*((i-21)/36)*((i-22)/35)*((i-23)/34)*((i-24)/33)*((i-25)/32)*((i-26)/31)*((i-27)/30)*((i-28)/29)*((i-29)/28)*((i-30)/27)*((i-31)/26)*((i-32)/25)*((i-33)/24)*((i-34)/23)*((i-35)/22)*((i-36)/21)*((i-37)/20)*((i-38)/19)*((i-39)/18)*((i-40)/17)*((i-41)/16)*((i-42)/15)*((i-43)/14)*((i-44)/13)*((i-45)/12)*((i-46)/11)*((i-47)/10)*((i-48)/9)*((i-49)/8)*((i-50)/7)*((i-51)/6)*((i-52)/5)*((i-53)/4)*((i-54)/3)*((i-55)/2)*((i-56)/1))+-126849859681465840*Math.round(1*((i-0)/58)*((i-1)/57)*((i-2)/56)*((i-3)/55)*((i-4)/54)*((i-5)/53)*((i-6)/52)*((i-7)/51)*((i-8)/50)*((i-9)/49)*((i-10)/48)*((i-11)/47)*((i-12)/46)*((i-13)/45)*((i-14)/44)*((i-15)/43)*((i-16)/42)*((i-17)/41)*((i-18)/40)*((i-19)/39)*((i-20)/38)*((i-21)/37)*((i-22)/36)*((i-23)/35)*((i-24)/34)*((i-25)/33)*((i-26)/32)*((i-27)/31)*((i-28)/30)*((i-29)/29)*((i-30)/28)*((i-31)/27)*((i-32)/26)*((i-33)/25)*((i-34)/24)*((i-35)/23)*((i-36)/22)*((i-37)/21)*((i-38)/20)*((i-39)/19)*((i-40)/18)*((i-41)/17)*((i-42)/16)*((i-43)/15)*((i-44)/14)*((i-45)/13)*((i-46)/12)*((i-47)/11)*((i-48)/10)*((i-49)/9)*((i-50)/8)*((i-51)/7)*((i-52)/6)*((i-53)/5)*((i-54)/4)*((i-55)/3)*((i-56)/2)*((i-57)/1))+189776303470473200*Math.round(1*((i-0)/59)*((i-1)/58)*((i-2)/57)*((i-3)/56)*((i-4)/55)*((i-5)/54)*((i-6)/53)*((i-7)/52)*((i-8)/51)*((i-9)/50)*((i-10)/49)*((i-11)/48)*((i-12)/47)*((i-13)/46)*((i-14)/45)*((i-15)/44)*((i-16)/43)*((i-17)/42)*((i-18)/41)*((i-19)/40)*((i-20)/39)*((i-21)/38)*((i-22)/37)*((i-23)/36)*((i-24)/35)*((i-25)/34)*((i-26)/33)*((i-27)/32)*((i-28)/31)*((i-29)/30)*((i-30)/29)*((i-31)/28)*((i-32)/27)*((i-33)/26)*((i-34)/25)*((i-35)/24)*((i-36)/23)*((i-37)/22)*((i-38)/21)*((i-39)/20)*((i-40)/19)*((i-41)/18)*((i-42)/17)*((i-43)/16)*((i-44)/15)*((i-45)/14)*((i-46)/13)*((i-47)/12)*((i-48)/11)*((i-49)/10)*((i-50)/9)*((i-51)/8)*((i-52)/7)*((i-53)/6)*((i-54)/5)*((i-55)/4)*((i-56)/3)*((i-57)/2)*((i-58)/1))+51028516348018696*Math.round(1*((i-0)/60)*((i-1)/59)*((i-2)/58)*((i-3)/57)*((i-4)/56)*((i-5)/55)*((i-6)/54)*((i-7)/53)*((i-8)/52)*((i-9)/51)*((i-10)/50)*((i-11)/49)*((i-12)/48)*((i-13)/47)*((i-14)/46)*((i-15)/45)*((i-16)/44)*((i-17)/43)*((i-18)/42)*((i-19)/41)*((i-20)/40)*((i-21)/39)*((i-22)/38)*((i-23)/37)*((i-24)/36)*((i-25)/35)*((i-26)/34)*((i-27)/33)*((i-28)/32)*((i-29)/31)*((i-30)/30)*((i-31)/29)*((i-32)/28)*((i-33)/27)*((i-34)/26)*((i-35)/25)*((i-36)/24)*((i-37)/23)*((i-38)/22)*((i-39)/21)*((i-40)/20)*((i-41)/19)*((i-42)/18)*((i-43)/17)*((i-44)/16)*((i-45)/15)*((i-46)/14)*((i-47)/13)*((i-48)/12)*((i-49)/11)*((i-50)/10)*((i-51)/9)*((i-52)/8)*((i-53)/7)*((i-54)/6)*((i-55)/5)*((i-56)/4)*((i-57)/3)*((i-58)/2)*((i-59)/1))}
```

This polynomial function (simplified to degree 25 and without rounding) plotted, look at values for whole numbers (readable for [6;19]) :

> [image]

Tests :

```
for (var i=0; i<60; i++) { console.log(i + ' : ' + digitsum(i)) }
0 : 0
1 : 1
2 : 2
3 : 3
4 : 4
5 : 5
6 : 6
7 : 7
8 : 8
9 : 9
10 : 1
11 : 2
12 : 3
13 : 4
14 : 5
15 : 6
16 : 7
17 : 8
18 : 9
19 : 10
20 : 2
21 : 3
22 : 4
23 : 5
24 : 6
25 : 7
26 : 8
27 : 9
28 : 10
29 : 11
30 : 3
31 : 4
32 : 5
33 : 6
34 : 7
35 : 8
36 : 9
37 : 10
38 : 11
39 : 12
40 : 4
41 : 5
42 : 6
43 : 7
44 : 8
45 : 9
46 : 10
47 : 11
48 : 12
49 : 13
50 : 5
51 : 6
52 : 7
53 : 8
54 : 9
55 : 10
56 : 12 //precision issue starts here
57 : 16
58 : 16
59 : 0
```

Comment: +1 This is cool. Instead of a polynomial interpolation you might want to do a spline interpolation though, that should also be possible to do with an evolutionary algorithm, but it might be more precise.

Comment: @SztupY, interesting ! I'm not used to work with spline but I will certainly have a look at this method. Thanks.